# SQL Server 2016 - Disparity Between View Definition and View Design

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, view, system-tables

I've run into an interesting issue with some databases I've inherited, and could use some help unpacking it all.

**The Issue**

After adding a column to a table, views selecting * from that table are now breaking in strange ways. The best way for me to illustrate is to repro it, so here goes.

**Repro**

Here's my table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable1 (
    col1 INT,
    col2 varchar(12)
)

CREATE TABLE TestTable2 (
    col3 INT,
    col4 varchar(12)
)
```

And some test data:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable1 VALUES
  (1,'abc')
, (2,'def')
, (3,'ghi')
, (4,'jkl')

INSERT INTO TestTable2 VALUES
  (1,'ABC')
, (2,'DEF')
, (3,'GHI')
, (4,'JKL')
```

Now the View definition (and yes I know views should have an explicit column set. Whoever wrote this one did not):

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS

SELECT 
    tt1.*
    , tt2.col4
FROM TestTable1 AS tt1
INNER JOIN TestTable2 AS tt2
ON tt1.col1 = tt2.col3
GO
```

As you'd expect, this is the result when I SELECT * FROM TestView:

```
col1        col2         col4
----------- ------------ ------------
1           abc          ABC
2           def          DEF
3           ghi          GHI
4           jkl          JKL
```

Super sensible. Here's where it runs off the rails - I add a column to TestTable1:

```
ALTER TABLE TestTable1
ADD col5 varchar(8)
```

And having done so, here's what the view now returns:

```
col1        col2         col4
----------- ------------ --------
1           abc          NULL
2           def          NULL
3           ghi          NULL
4           jkl          NULL
```

Because of course it does. However, if I run the same query used to define the view, I get:

```
col1        col2         col5     col4
----------- ------------ -------- ------------
1           abc          NULL     ABC
2           def          NULL     DEF
3           ghi          NULL     GHI
4           jkl          NULL     JKL
```

Which is exactly what I'd expect. So what's happened? I've tried every method I can find to query the view definition to see what's changed:

```
SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM information_schema.views WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TestView'

EXEC sp_helptext 'TestView'

SELECT definition 
FROM sys.objects AS o
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.object_id = object_id( 'dbo.TestView')
  and o.type      = 'V'
```

And each one returns the definition exactly as it was originally defined. It's not until I use the SQL Server Management Studio Design tool that I see something different:

```
SELECT        tt1.col1, tt1.col2, tt1.col5 AS col4, tt2.col4
FROM            dbo.TestTable1 AS tt1 INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TestTable2 AS tt2 ON tt1.col1 = tt2.col3
```

It's the work of a lunatic. It's easily fixed by updating the view to use explicit columns rather than the wildcard *. However, what I'm seeing is that this database and table are referenced in myriad views across multiple databases.

**The Question**

So my question is thus - where is the metadata/definition for this nonsensical version of the view, and why does it trump what is supposedly the unambiguous definition of the view?

Comment: You can avoid this issue by [not using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), using [WITH SCHEMABINDING](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4673/benefits-of-schemabinding-in-sql-server/), etc.

Answer (score 2):

The view will run according to it's metadata, which is no longer correct.

If you run sp_refreshview, it should work correctly.

```
sp_refreshview  @viewname =  'TestView' ;

select * from TestView ;

+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col5 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | abc  | NULL | ABC  |
|    2 | def  | NULL | DEF  |
|    3 | ghi  | NULL | GHI  |
|    4 | jkl  | NULL | JKL  |
+------+------+------+------+
```